# How to sum total Time from from data in sql to gridview

Tags: c#, insert, sum, hour

string timeFromYourTextBox = label1.Text;
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(timeFromYourTextBox);

```
            string q2 = "insert into HoursStats (Hours, Bills) values ('" + time+ "','" + this.textBox1.Text + " ') ;";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ss);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q2, con);
            SqlDataReader read;
            con.Open();
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read()) { };
```

Comment: Insert doesn't return data. Did you mean to do a SELECT?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information before anyone can answer this. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reformat your question.

Comment: Thank  you  for your recommend  i am new here becuae of that.  my question  was how to sum total of hours from db in gridview this code is my insert dor hours and bills for my bills i write code for sum and works but for hours i don't  know how to code to sum total of hours  with the same code like bills not working because of type of data